# Linq to SQL Exception When Record is Updated from Two Different Applications

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, orm

I am working with two C# Winform applications that use Linq to SQL for database access.  All of my database access and queries exist in a DLL project that is referenced and used by both of these applications.  The first application synchronizes data between an accounting application and a SQL server database.  The second application reads, writes, and updates records in the same database.  Currently, the DataContext is not disposed in either application until the program exits.  Therefore, application 1 (synchronizing external app with SQL DB) and application 2 (create, read, update SQL DB) each have a reference to the database library which contains the context and DAOs.  The first time they need DB access, an instance of the context is instantiated inside of a Singleton.  The exception that I have encountered and steps to re-produce it are below.

1) Start up application 1
2) Start up application 2
3) Run application 1 which basically updates records in the SQL database based on some external accounting system.
4) Attempt to update one of the records modified by application 1

The mapping for the column in exception below is:

```
<Column Name="TimeStamp" Type="System.Data.Linq.Binary" DbType="rowversion NOT NULL" CanBeNull="false" IsVersion="true" />
```

Also, Update Check is set to never.  I realize that it may be a better design to dispose of the dc more frequently but, that is not an immediate option since customers are using this application.  Is there a way to solve this problem?

```
03/14/2013 15:18:08 Error BEN-LAPTOP Scribble.Database.Utilities.Domain.Persistence.Repository`1.SaveAll System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
03/14/2013 15:18:08 Error BEN-LAPTOP Scribble.Database.Utilities.Domain.Persistence.Repository`1.SaveAll Value of member 'TimeStamp' of an object of type 'Boat' changed.
A member that is computed or generated by the database cannot be changed.
03/14/2013 15:18:08 Error BEN-LAPTOP Scribble.Database.Utilities.Domain.Persistence.Repository`1.SaveAll    at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.CheckForInvalidChanges(TrackedObject tracked)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at Scribble.Database.Utilities.DomainClassesDataContext.Submit(RefreshMode refreshMode) in C:\Aaron\Dev\ScribbleUtilityProjects\Scribble.Database.Utilities\DomainClasses.cs:line 42
   at Scribble.Database.Utilities.DomainClassesDataContext.SubmitOverwriteDatabase() in C:\Aaron\Dev\ScribbleUtilityProjects\Scribble.Database.Utilities\DomainClasses.cs:line 19
   at Scribble.Database.Utilities.Domain.Persistence.Repository`1.SaveAll() in C:\Aaron\Dev\ScribbleUtilityProjects\Scribble.Database.Utilities\Domain\Persistence\Repository.cs:line 79
03/14/2013 15:18:08 Error BEN-LAPTOP MarineService.GlobalCollections.showAndLogErrors Value of member 'TimeStamp' of an object of type 'Boat' changed.
A member that is computed or generated by the database cannot be changed.
03/14/2013 15:18:08 Error BEN-LAPTOP MarineService.GlobalCollections.showAndLogErrors    at Scribble.Database.Utilities.Domain.Persistence.Repository`1.SaveAll() in C:\Aaron\Dev\ScribbleUtilityProjects\Scribble.Database.Utilities\Domain\Persistence\Repository.cs:line 101
   at Scribble.Database.Utilities.Domain.Persistence.Repository`1.UpdateEntity(T entity, Boolean attach) in C:\Aaron\Dev\ScribbleUtilityProjects\Scribble.Database.Utilities\Domain\Persistence\Repository.cs:line 50
   at MarineService.Tests.AddWorkOrderForm.SaveWorkOrder() in C:\Aaron\Dev\ScribbleApplicationProjects\PureService\AddWorkOrderForm.cs:line 1638
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want your context to be a singleton. From the DataContext page on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx):

> In general, a DataContext instance is designed to last for one "unit
>   of work" however your application defines that term. A DataContext is
>   lightweight and is not expensive to create. A typical LINQ to SQL
>   application creates DataContext instances at method scope or as a
>   member of short-lived classes that represent a logical set of related
>   database operations.

Comment: Okay, so lets assume that there is not a Singleton involved.  If I have two separate Winform applications.  First application instantiates DC, Second application instantiates DC, while first app is using DC to perform a bunch of updates, application 2 also attempts to update a record that has been modified by application 1 since it loaded.  Same exception, how do I solve this?

Comment: The second line of your error log indicates that optimistic locking is being used. You can't entirely eliminate this type of error with optimistic locking in a concurrent environment, it's the nature of the beast. You simply have to retry (making whatever adjustments you need to for the changes that happened while you weren't looking). You minimize the frequency of these errors by keeping your context lifetimes as short as possible.

Comment: My understanding is that if I have a timestamp on the table then only this column will be checked to verify that the record has not been changed.  So, if app 1 updates a record that app 2 attempts to update a second later the timestamp value that app 2 has in the cache would not be the same as the timestamp in the DB.  So, if Linq is refusing the update in app 2 due to the different timestamp, what should I do in this situation?  I thought that submitting the update like this: this.Submit(System.Data.Linq.RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues); would solve the issue but, I guess not.  I'm new to this.

Comment: I don't use Linq-to-SQL myself so I can only point you at MSDN's [conflict resolution how-to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399389.aspx) I'm afraid.